# File::make('Fichier', 'path')->storeOriginalName('original_name') gives me gEUBH18u1UdjoPBS0POQB64xit5PF05Rnl8M5lMI.pdf

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova,

I want to upload a file to S3. As this file is generated automatically, I know it has already a good naming. So, I want to keep original filename. But when using:

```
        File::make('Fichier', 'path')
            ->disk('s3')
            ->storeOriginalName('path')
```

I realized that my file, originally named `FILE1.pdf` now is named  `gEUBH18u1UdjoPBS0POQB64xit5PF05Rnl8M5lMI.pdf`

Why ?

Comment: did you try using `Storage` instead of FIle?. Like this `Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('[file path]', [file name], '[public / private]')`

Comment: Nop, File:: is a Laravel Nova field. https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/file-fields.html

Comment: try this one https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/file-fields.html?#customizing-file-storage

Comment: click this anchor `#Customizing File Storage`